# JavaScript - Can't read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object

Okay, this might be a stupid question, because I'm missing something, but I just can't seem to figure out what!

this is my object, using `{{ definitionList | json }}`

```
{
  "State": "Success",
  "Data": [
    {
      "Description": "Default",
      "ID": 4,
    },
    {
      "Description": "Hello World",
      "ID": 14,
    },
    {
      "Description": "Test Def",
      "ID": 11,
    },
    {
      "Description": "test definitie",
      "ID": 12,
    },
    {
      "Description": "testffvfvfvffv",
      "ID": 8,
    },
    {
      "Description": "Werknemer_kantoor",
      "ID": 3,
      "Type": 
    },
    {
      "Description": "Werknemer_kantoor",
      "ID": 6,
    }
  ],
  "Error": null
}
```

okay now I want to print out "Data" uisng `{{ definitionList.Data | json }}`

and I receive the error

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'Data' of undefined

I don't understand why? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you're loading `definitionList` asynchronously and `definitionList` is not yet defined when your template is executed? Try `{{ definitionList?.Data | json }}` (with a `?`).

Comment: We can't help you without more specifics. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What happens when you try `{{ definitionList[0].Data | json }}`?

Comment: @AngularFrance lol, oh my god thank you very much that was it! Second time today!

Comment: @AngularFrance - cut & paste your comment into an answer so the OP can tick it and anyone coming to this in 20 years knows there is an answer.

Comment: Sure! @Nicolas, can you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're loading `definitionList` asynchronously and it is not yet defined when your template is executed?

Try the following code instead (note the `?`):

```html
{{ definitionList?.Data | json }}
```